# optocoupler output protection

Tags: opto-isolator, tvs

I've got this circuit. The target generates an identical PWM signal to control the intensity of 3 LEDS. But I would like to protect the output of these optocouplers with this TVS:

[image]

I'm not sure if using the TVS SMBJ78Ca is the best option: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/SM/SMBJ100A.pdf

Max Vce [ACPL-271-500E] = 80V

The design schematic is only to distribute the PWM intensity signal to three different LES drivers.

The PWM outputs only control de intensity pin of a LED driver tps92551 [Pin3 DIM].

Best regards.

---

The design schematic is only to distribute the PWM intensity signal to three different LES drivers.

The PWM outputs only control de intensity pin of a LED driver tps92551 [Pin3 DIM].

Best regards.

Comment: Why are you using opto-couplers? Why do you feel the need to protect the LEDs with a couple of TVS? Spec'ing the TVS depends a lot on the application. Also, why are these LEDs all in series with each other? Putting a lot more current through the opto-isolators than you need to...

Comment: @AndyHall the LEDs are all in series because that is an efficient way of driving them from a 5V rail.

Comment: But from what are you "protecting" anything? It's not like you have a high voltage that you are isolating and end-user from - it's a 5V supply. The entire optocoupler business (not to mention the TVS) seems utterly pointless - parts and complexity without any obvious point to them...

Comment: 5 V is not enough to turn on three LEDs in the opto-couplers reliably. At 10 mA you will have lost 1 V on the series resistor and another bit on the Q.

Comment: @transistor incorrect, the typical forward voltage of one LED in the opto specified is 1.2 volts. Even with the max of 1.4 volts you have a typical 0.8 volts remaining to current limit with.

Comment: Agreed. They're probably infra-red LEDs (since nobody's looking at them) and the forward voltage drops the more we move towards the red end of the spectrum. Brain updated with new information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outputs from the opto device (C and E) are effectively a BJT collector and emitter. It will not produce any voltage to drive the LEDs therefore the LEDs will not activate. This means the TVS on each is pointless: -

[image]

Here's how you interface the output: -

[image]

You need a power supply on the transistor side and a resistor to current limit the transistor. An LED can be inserted in series with the resistor.

Comment: Hi Andy, You are right, but, in this case, the destination of the PWM signal is going to be the TPS92551 - Pin3 Dim (Led Driver). This pin has a pull-up current source so it's going to work fine. I realize that in the scheme there is an error, I going to answer the question with a proposal from Wurth Elektronik and I'm going to upload the right schematic.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your contributions. This is the final schematic (Notice I've had to change the schematic due to an error. This schematic is proven and works fine). Wurth Elecktronik has recommended to me this TVS doiode: http://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/824021.pdf

[image: ACPL-217-500E ESD Protection]

Comment: You really have not addressed why you need a TVS diode. They will not offer any protection to some "problem" that is clearly visible in your question. You haven't addressed any of the comments under your question - nobody seems to think you have made a case for TVS diodes and your whole question is based on this premise.

Comment: Hi Andy, My target is to meet EMC, so I need to protect the output. Best regards.

Comment: Protect from what? Emc has little to do with tvs diodes.

Comment: You can see the datsheet: [824021](http://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/824021.pdf)

Comment: I don't want to see the data sheet for the TVS - I want YOU to justify why you need a TVS. Bottom line is you don't need one!

Comment: Hi Andy, I would like to meet with IEC 61000-4-2, IEC 61000-4-4 (EFT) and IEC 61000-4-5.

Comment: But where is the circuit problem coming from that will create non-compliance?

Comment: @Andyaka looks like he's driving an LED strip... which is basically an antenna. Which is where you EMC part would come in, but I think he just typoed and meant ESD as those IEC standards he mentioned are all ESD related and that also explains the need for the TVS.